# Android View not Refreshing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried using `invalidate()` to refresh my view, and it will not work. I know there is another way to refresh using `draw(Canvas canvas)`.

Could someone explain to me how and why to use the draw method?
What is the Canvas? (is that the view I would like redrawn?)

This is some sample code in how it would be used:

```
    if(pageNumber == 1)
    {
        if(pageCount == --lastPageCount)
        {
            page2Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            page1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(created1 == false)
        {
            help.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            help.setLayoutParams(params);

            helpText.setLayoutParams(params);
            helpText.setText("TEST!\n\n" + 
                    "test\n" +
                    "Test");

            help.addView(helpText);
            page1Layout.addView(help);
            newSheetLayoutV.addView(page1Layout);
            created1 = true;
        }
    }
```

There is also another part/parts to this code which is not working as it should (this is why I need to use the refresh).

```
    else if(pageNumber == 4)
    {
        if(pageCount == ++lastPageCount)
        {
            page3Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            page4Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (pageCount == --lastPageCount)
        {
            page5Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            page4Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if(created4 == false)
        {
            LinearLayout horizontalPageLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            horizontalPageLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            horizontalPageLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView testText = new TextView(this);
            testText.setLayoutParams(params);
            testText.setText("Test!");

            page4Layout.addView(testText);

            newSheetLayoutV.addView(page4Layout);

            created4 = true;
        }
    }
```

Essentially the code works fine, except for the refresh when I remove the view `page1Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`, and add a new view to the layout!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, added the `visibility(View.GONE);` and addView to the creation of the layouts, then just make the layouts visible when there was a need for them.